# How to can I use TFTree Visualization of rqt in ROS2 ( dashing and foxy )

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I use ROS2 Dashing, I cannot find TFTree Visualization menu in rqt.

How to can I use TFTree Visualization of rqt in ROS2 ( dashing and foxy ) ?

When I use ROS1 Melodic, I can find TFtree Visualization menu like Plugins -> Visualization -> TFtree.
Please help me.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357133/how-to-can-i-use-tftree-visualization-of-rqt-in-ros2-(-dashing-and-foxy-)/) by [hyunoklee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35908/hyunoklee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

self answering problem, use rqt --clear-config , I can see tftree menu in rqt

---

Originally posted by [hyunoklee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35908/hyunoklee/) with karma: 36 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mirella melo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55539/mirella-melo/) on 2020-10-19**:
Did it work for you at all? When I select the 'TF tree', I got:

service not available, waiting again...

service not available, waiting again...

service not available, waiting again...

**Comment by [RobotDreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/40559/robotdreams/) on 2021-07-08**:
Same as OP no TF Tree option
Foxy - "rqt --clear-config" did nothing

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2023-01-14**:
I had a similar issue on humble
It worked after I installed `ros-humble-tf2-tools` and `ros-humble-rqt-tf-tree` and executed `rqt --clear-config`